# Scala implicit conversion conflict strangely

Tags: scala, implicit

I found a strange compiling error:

```
class A
class B

object M {
  implicit val mA: M[A] = d => new A
  implicit val mB: M[B] = d => new B
}

trait M[K] {
  def get(d: D): K
}

object D {
  implicit def f[K](d: D)(implicit m: M[K]): K = m.get(d)
}

class D

object Main {
  val d = new D
  val a: A = d // This line can't compile!
}
```

That can't compile caused by `mA` and `mB` conflict.
But that is strange since type `B` doesn't match our result type.

If I comment the `mB` like this

```
class A
class B

object M {
  implicit val mA: M[A] = d => new A
  //implicit val mB: M[B] = d => new B
}

trait M[K] {
  def get(d: D): K
}

object D {
  implicit def f[K](d: D)(implicit m: M[K]): K = m.get(d)
}

class D

object Main {
  val d = new D
  val a: A = d // can compile
}
```

That can compile. Why can't the first case compile?

Comment: For what it's worth, Dotty (run on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/)) has no problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when compiler try to find implicit variable to pass as `m` to `f` it doesn't know expected return type (because it depends on which implicit variable will be selected). It creates kind of circular dependency.

PS: You don't need to make `f` implicit to illustrate this problem.